# Loopback 4: Test never end when there is a connection with a MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, testing, strongloop, loopback

Launch npm test, but it never end. It happens when there is a connection with a MongoDB involve. It is rare because the test works, but it never ends.

```
before('setupApplication', async () => {
        ({ app, client } = await setupApplication());
        //await prepareTestData()
    });

    after(async () => {
        //await cleanupTestData();
        await app.stop();
    });

    it('login with a test user', async () => {
        const res = await client.post('/user-accounts/login').set('urlLogin', TEST_TENANT_URL)
            .send({
                email: TEST_EMAIL,
                password: TEST_PASS
            }).expect(200);
        token = res.body.token;
        expect(res.body).to.ownProperty("token").and.length(EXPECTED_TOKEN_LENGTH);
        console.log("Logged in with token ", res.body.token);
    });
```

The problem: The terminal never end. Is like a thread still working. I don´t know if it is a problem with loopback or what.

Any idea? I hope somebody could help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Cross-posting my comment from the discussion in [https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/3672:](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/3672:_)*

Please use Mocha option `exit`, it will end the process after all tests (and after/afterEach hooks) have finished. See https://mochajs.org/#configuring-mocha-nodejs to learn more. Alternatively, you can add `--exit` option to `mocha` CLI, e.g. `mocha --exit src/__tests__/**/*.js`.